# NuxtChild not showing child component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

[image]

On _collection.vue I have something like

```html
<div>
   This is a collection
   <NuxtChild />
</div>
```

And inside of category > index.vue I have content like

```html
<div>
   This is a Bicycle Page
</div>
```

If I go to http://localhost:3000/collection/bicycle
It will only show This is a Bicycle page but it will not show the parent layout.

What am I doing wrong?

Isn't _collection.vue the parent of anything inside of the _category folder? Shouldn't everything _collection.vue show in addition to the child components?

Comment: Here `_category` and `_collection` are at the same level, so it's basically one of them. You cannot have 2 variables at the same time, it's like asking: "what is my variable: X or Y?". You can have only 1 dynamic page, especially at the same level. If you want to have `/collectin/bicycle`, then `collection` directory and `_type.vue` (for bicycle) inside of it should be enough.

Comment: Thanks @kissu, got confused there for a second. Using _category.vue and removing NuxtChild worked. I originally was going to do it collection/bike/productId but decided to link all products to product/slug instead so I don't even need the nuxt-child but good to know for the future

Comment: Yes it was solved thank you

Comment: @kissu if you copy your comment and post as an answer I'll mark as complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `_category` and `_collection` are at the same level, so it's basically one of them.

You cannot have 2 variables at the same time, it's like asking: "what is my variable: X or Y?".

You can have only 1 dynamic page, especially at the same level. If you want to have `/collection/bicycle`, then `collection` directory and `_type.vue` (for bicycle) inside of it should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mixed up the concepts of pages, components and layouts here.

If you are trying to set up a layout that is applied to each page in `pages/collection`, you could make use of an actual [layout](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/layouts/).

If you are trying to display a particular piece of content on multiple pages, you should use [components](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/components).

Further information around [nested route handling](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages#nested-routes).

Answer (score 0):

Just change a `_collection.vue` to `index.vue` If you want to have `collection` path as dynamic value, change **folder** name to `_collection`. And as kissu wrote you in a comment, you have two routes at the same level, so it reads just one. All you need to do is change `_collection.vue` file name if you don't need a flexible route.